# Adobe CQ EXTJS component data post to servlet

Tags: extjs, adobe, aem, crx

I got a EXTJS CQ component with two text fields and and button.

When the "save" button clicked, the dialog data has to be submitted to custom sling servlet.
Custom sling servlet will call a osgi service and finally saves data to crx using jcr api.

Question : How to post the dialog data to servlet ?

I am new to CQ, Thanks for any help!

-Sri

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming when you say "save" you are referring to some custom button and not the "OK" button that saves the dialog data to the node.

Add a [handler](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.Ext.Button) to the save button. The handler function must retrieve the dialog object, loop over all the fields in it  and post the values to your custom servlet. The handler should be something like this

```
function(button,event){
//fetch dialog using  the save button
  var dialog = button.findParentByType('dialog');
  var params = {}; //parameters to post
  var textfields = dialog.findByType('textfield'); //returns all textfields in the dialog 
  for(i=0;i<textfields.length;i++){
      params[textfields[i].name] = textfields[i].getValue(); //add the value to params with name same as the name you have provided to the textfield
  }
  $.post( "path to your servlet" , params ); // you can also use CQ.shared.HTTP of cq's ext js package to do the post
}
```

In case all you want to do is post the form data on clicking the "OK" button that comes by default, set the **[formurl](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.Dialog)** property of the dialog to the path of your custom servlet. In this case if the values aren't stored back as properties with appropriate  names on the corresponding node like a dialog normally does, the dialog will not be able to load the values when the component is re-edited.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am thinking to use CQ.HTTP.POST method. I will give it a try.