# How to store encoded values of special characters in AEM property?

Tags: javascript, servlets, aem, crx

I have a requirement like entering special characters in dialog. 
In page level it should display the special chars (it's working fine)

I written a beforesubmit function such that, before storing the value into the crx, I'm replacing special characters with respected encoded value. In alert, it's coming fine. But in crx, its not reflecting.

Comment: What exactly do you see in crx? How do you encode characters?

Comment: Im replacing special characters with customer desired values. For eg: Replacing © with '&copy'. Likewise I can able to do for all special characters. After changing it also, in CRX it is getting stored as special characters only instead of that encoded(changed) values.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is possibly answered here - [Adobe CQ EXTJS component data post to servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26373623/adobe-cq-extjs-component-data-post-to-servlet)

You could have your own servlet that encodes data before persisting it to CRX.

Comment: I want to do it in dialog level.Whenever I enter data in dialog , after clicking on OK button I'm dng the encoding in the 'beforesubmit' function. But when it gets saved, it saves as special characters only in CRX.